# How to monitor map service connections ArcGIS Service?

Tags: arcgis-server

I would like to see the historical data on the number of users that have connected to a map or feature service in ArcGIS Server. Is this available in the logs?  If not, is there a way to do execute this task?  I am using ArcGIS Server 10.

Comment: That sort of logging (and pretty displays) was added to newer releases.  10.0 is now Retired, so a back-port isn't in the realm of possibility.  If you have a really sophisticated proxy this would be possible, but it wouldn't be retroactive to before it was installed.

Comment: You could look at server logs as long as your server logging levels are set properly. Using "Fine" logging level or lower gives you  service level operations which you could use for this purpose.  These would be available for as long as your logs are retained. It would be a matter of querying the logs and summarizing based on the service name and some return code